# Randomize some strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, random

I want to randomize some strings like this.

Default String :

```
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven
```

I need to Have :

```
six,three,one,seven,two,four,five
```

I just need to make random the order of every one , seperating with `,` .

How to do it in PHP ?

Comment: It is OK to provide some proof of concept of what you have already tried, even if you had no success and yielded no results :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = 'one,two,three,four,five,six,seven';
$myArray = explode(',', $input);
shuffle($myArray);
echo implode(',', $myArray);
```

[Works like a charm](https://eval.in/172401).

Answer (score 2):

```
// We can't shuffle a list, but we can shuffle an array.

$things = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven');

// Shuffle randomly changes the order of the array. It uses references so it doesn't
// make a copy of the array.

shuffle($things);

// then to display on the screen, either

foreach ($things as $thing) {
    echo $thing.'<br>';
}

// or

echo implode(',', $things);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two arrays. In the first, put the ordered list.

```
$things = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven');
```

Then create a random number array that has the same number of elements as the $things array.

```
$numItems = count($things)
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++) {
        $randomLst[$i] = $i;
        $temparray[$i] = mt_rand(0, 1073741823);
    }
    array_multisort($temparray, SORT_ASC, $randomLst, SORT_ASC);
```

So now you have your array of items and a random array of numbers. Use the random array of numbers to call your array of items. Something like this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++) {
   echo $things[$randomLst][i];
}
```

When you need a new shuffled list, create a new $randomLst.